# Ruby OOP, SOAP request with Savon: "uninitialized constant CustomError (NameError)"

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I am very new to OOP programming with Ruby and using the Savon gem to make requests to a SOAP XML Webservice / API.
I was able to successfully see responses back when using a much more simplified non object oriented approach but I wanted to refactor my code and ensure that it is extendible and works in Rails later. I'm sure it's something pretty simple but I have no idea where I'm going wrong! Please help, thanks very much in advance!

Below is my ruby file `reserve.rb`:

```
require 'savon'

class Reservation
  attr_accessor :first_name

def initialize(options={})
  @first_name = options[:first_name]
end

def client
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://some_wdsl_url_link", adapter: :curb, follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
end

def first_name(confirm_number, email) 
  message = { confirmation_number: confirm_number, email: email }
  response = client.call(:search_for_reservation, message: message)
  response.body[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation][:first_name]
rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error
  fault_code = error.to_hash[:fault][:faultcode]
  raise CustomError, fault_code
end

end
reserve = Reservation.new
puts reserve.first_name("NTSOTHJN", "otherjamesgray@gmail.com")
```

And here is the output in the terminal when I run ruby `reserve.rb`:

```
reserve.rb:20:in `rescue in first_name': uninitialized constant Reservation::CustomError (NameError)
    from reserve.rb:15:in `first_name'
    from reserve.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Where did you put definition of your `CustomError`?

Comment: @PawełDawczak I'm not sure but I think this is being called from the Savon gem required at top. I copied that part from this tutorial: http://www.leighhalliday.com/savon-soap-doesnt-leave-you-feeling-dirty under this sub-heading - "Wrap all of your API calls inside of a class."

Comment: In that case, it looks just like an example of what you can do, but it is not the final code that will work. You should create your own `*Error` to handle exceptions

Comment: Thanks @PawełDawczak I commented out the error handling and changed message hash to use strings with old hash rocket syntax. This is returning the correct information (first_name) from the xml now. But just out of interest is the attr_accessor and def initialize method necessary?

Comment: I think they are not. As mentioned earlier - this is just an example, so you should modify it to fit your needs

Comment: @PawełDawczak thanks, I added the initialize and attr_accessor lines myself after as I thought this would fix the uninitialized constant error, but the error messsage was a misnomer / misled me, thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!